# Paginated pages are showing correct content but pagination links are not

Tags: wp-query, pagination, frontpage, paginate-links

I am using a custom `WP_Query` to display posts on static front page. and generating [numbered pagination links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) with `paginate_links` functions. This is the code I have...

```
$latest_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__not_in' => array( 3 ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$latest_query = new WP_Query( $latest_args );

if ( $latest_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $latest_query->have_posts() ) : $latest_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;

    if ( $latest_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
        $big = 999999999;
        echo '<div class="pagination">';
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $latest_query->max_num_pages
        ) );
        echo '</div>';
    endif;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

But when I use this on my `static front page` then it always show first page content on all other pages too. But it was corrected by adding paged parameter to query [as suggested in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#static_front_page).

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
  $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
  $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
  $paged = 1;
}
```

Which fixed the duplicate content on paginated pages but number based pagination links are always stick to first page. It always displays first link (1) as current which makes difficult to browse rest of the pages.

Although this code works fine if I use it on any other page except `static front page`.

Any solution to this issue.

**EDIT: Update**

I have tried disabling all plugins and removed all custom developed functions from `functions.php` but the problem still exists. So I am guessing this has to do something with how I am using `WP_Query` or `paginate_links` function.

There should be some mistake in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static pages doesn't work with `paged` query variable, they need the `page` variable.

This is the reason why your second code block makes the query work: it uses the `page` var when available.

However, your paginated links code always use `paged`:

```
...
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
...
```

So you are *sending* `paged` query var but *looking for* `page` var.

Solution is to make your `format` argument send `page` query var if used from a static page.

```
if ( $latest_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :

    $var = is_page() ? 'page' : 'paged'; // <-- choose var here   

    $big = 999999999;
    echo '<div class="pagination">';
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),

        'format' => '?' . $var . '=%#%', // <-- use var here  

        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var($var) ), // <-- use var here 
        'total' => $latest_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
    echo '</div>';
endif;
```

**Untested**.

Comment: I think you are correct on the `format` part. I can remember having to do this once but wasn't 100% sure about that. But on top of my head, you are correct

Comment: How silly! I totally missed it. This works but I also had to change `'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') )` too. Thanks G.M.

Comment: @Roberthue Glad it worked. I updated the answer to use `$var` in for "current" argument too.